# How to close jquery context menu on subsequent right-clicks

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, contextmenu

I implemented the jQuery ContextMenu plugin from Javascript Toolbox and it works beautifully. When I right click in certain specified areas, it opens the context menu that I want, so it works well in everything except for one thing:

When I right click to open a context menu when another menu is still open, it doesn't close the original context menu. As long as I click on a different row of my table, a new context menu is opened without closing the other ones.

They are all closed when I left-click however.

Some help, or even a push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**Plugin address:** http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/contextmenu/

EDIT: This is the code used to call the context menu

```
$("#sku_table tbody").mousedown(function(event) {
    if (event.which === 3) {

        var sku = $(event.target).closest('tr').attr('id');
        sku = sku.replace('.', '\\.');
        var menu1 = [
            {
            'Open Item information': {
                onclick: function(menuItem, menu) {
                    //Function to open item info
                }
            }}
        ];
        $(function() {
            $('#' + sku).contextMenu(menu1, {
                theme: 'vista'
            });
        });

    }
});​
```

What actually opens the menu is `$().contextMenu()`.

Comment: can I see your code for calling the context menu(s) please?

Comment: Here it is! If you need anything else let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that every time you make a right click inside the table body, a new instance of the context menu is created.  Instead, if you define the selector for what the context menu should appear on, the menu will only show up there.

If the context menu will show up on random items, those items should be defined with a class and the context menu can be instantiated from that class.

http://jsfiddle.net/azSMq/

```
$(function() {
    var menu1 = [
        {
        'Open Item information': {
            onclick: function(menuItem, menu) {
                $(this).fadeOut();
                //Function to open item info
            }
        }}
    ];
    $("#sku_table tr").contextMenu(menu1, {
        theme: 'vista'
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thank you sir. That makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
$("#sku_table tr").contextMenu(menu1, { theme: 'vista',
    beforeShow: function () {
        $(document).click();
        return true;
    } 
});
```

Forcing a document click will call internal code within the plugin that will auto hide other context menus

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that the demo page seems to work as desired in Firefox, but not in Chrome or IE.  One way to handle this would be to hide any open menus before displaying the one you have just right clicked.  So you could add this code:

```
$(".context-menu").hide();
```

add it after this line

```
if(event.which === 3){
```

That should give you the desired effect.

Comment: Works, but only hides (no pun intended) the problem, doesn't necessarily fix it. Thank you though, I hadn't thought of that.